# Как добиться одинакого эффекта затемнения заднего фона при управлении боковым меню с помощью свайпа, или же посредством кнопки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. [Есть страница с выезжающим (посредством бургера и swipe) слева меню](http://jsfiddle.net/exwna07g/3/)

Вобщем я хочу, чтобы при выезде меню слева, задний фон затемнялся. Я сделал так, что если вытаскивать и задвигать меню свайпом, то всё ок. Но я не могу никак синхронизировать этот эффект с кнопкой. Чтобы например вытащил свайпом, а задвинул бургером или наоборот.

Добавлял в js код такой фрагмент:

```
$("#shadow_window").toggleClass("shadow");
```

тобиш при клике на кнопку присваиваю блоку-маске класс с прозрачностью. Но во-первых это работает только на вытаскивание, а во-вторых если сначала вытащить/задвинуть свайпом, а потом попробовать вытащить с помощью кнопки, то фрагмент не работает.

Взято [отсюда](http://www.dejurka.ru/css/swipeable-side-menu/)

Comment: Вам необходимо установить `transition` https://webref.ru/css/transition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

что бы ваши обработчики события синхронизировались нужно немного "причесать" ваш код.

Во первых, нужно добавить 2 функции которые будут показывать и скрывать ваш sidebar.

Во вторых, в событии клик нужно добавить проверку открыт ли sidebar сейчас или нет, это делается при помощи [hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/).

В третьих, в обработчике события `swipeStatus` можно объединить два if оператора в if и else if [конструкцию](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_if_else.asp)

```js
$(window).ready(function() {
  function showSidebar() {
    $(".container").addClass("open-sidebar");
    $(".shadow_window").css("opacity", "0.6");
  }

  function hideSidebar() {
    $(".container").removeClass("open-sidebar");
    $(".shadow_window").css("opacity", "0");
  }

  $("[data-toggle]").click(function() {
    if ($(".container").hasClass("open-sidebar")) {
      hideSidebar();
    } else {
      showSidebar();
    }
  });

  $(".swipe-area").swipe({
    swipeStatus: function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers) {
      if (phase == "move" && direction == "right") {
        showSidebar();
      } else if (phase == "move" && direction == "left") {
        hideSidebar();
      }

      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за "причесанный" код! Всё работает))